# Spring boot Integration test RestController validation

Tags: spring-boot, spring-test

I create one @RestController, so I need to test my validation, so I create one model with and dont set any value, so my app will throw a lot of errors, so now I need to test this validation.

I create this method to validate:

```
@Test
    public void selarAberturaMatriculaFail() throws Exception {
        AberturaMatricula aberturaMatricula = new AberturaMatricula();
        MockHttpServletRequestBuilder requ = post("/ri/selo/abertura/").contentType(contentType).content(this.jsonWithClass(aberturaMatricula));
        mockMvc.perform(requ)
                .andExpect(model().attributeHasErrors("cns"));
    }
```

but I got this error:

> No ModelAndView found java.lang.AssertionError: No ModelAndView found

this is my Rest method:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/ri")
public class RIController {
@RequestMapping(value =  "/selo/abertura/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public AberturaMatricula selarAbertura(@RequestBody @Valid  AberturaMatricula aberturaMatricula){

...
    }
}
```

In my model I have cns property and more..

Answer (score 0):

You are not going to want to use a model test with a REST controller as REST simply returns the object and not a model and view.  See https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html#spring-mvc-test-framework as an example.  This tutorial http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/ also shows how to build some tests for REST services.